# Update with SUM in Same SQL Table

Tags: sql

I want to update SUM in same SQL table based on project id and Channel. for Total Channel= SUM(Channel 1 + Channel 2)

```
id | Channel       | Project_id | Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    Total Channel   PR1           10         10        10
2    Channel 1       PR1            5         5          5
3    Channel 2       PR1            5         5          5
4    Total Channel   PR2            20        40         30
5    Channel 1       PR2            10        20         15
6    Channel 2       PR2            10        20         15
7    Total Channel   PR3            30        50         10
8    Channel 1       PR3            15        25         5
9    Channel 2       PR3            15        25         5
```

I am trying with below Query, but something is wrong in this query

```
UPDATE 
    results AS r 
JOIN
    ( SELECT   project_id, 
               SUM(Column1) AS sum_column1,
               SUM(Column2) AS sum_column2,
               SUM(Column3) AS sum_column3,
      FROM     results 
      WHERE    channel <> 'Total Channel' and project_id=@project_id
      GROUP BY project_id
    ) AS grp
   ON  
       grp.project_id = r.project_id 
SET 
   r.column1 = grp.sum_column1,
   r.column2 = grp.sum_column2,
   r.column3 = grp.sum_column3
WHERE 
   r.project_id = @project_id and r.channel='Total Channel';
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Hello Bhushan. Please note that SQL is a catch-all term for languages that query relational databases. Each relational database system implements a dialect of SQL. Each dialect is sufficiently different that SQL for one database system will not work for another. When asking questions about SQL, always add a tag for your particular database system. E.g. one of Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: "something is wrong" is not helpful.  Does it return an error?  Does it return incorrect results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your database is but if it is MSSQL Server then it is straight forward using CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
;with cte_total
(
  select project_id, sum(column1) [c1total], sum(column2) [c2total], sum(column3) [c3total]
  from <YourTableName>
  where channel <> 'Total Channel'
  group by project_id
) 
update t
set column1 = c1Total, column2 = c2total, column3 = c3total
from <YourTableName> t
inner join cte_total ct ON (ct.project_id = t.project_id)
where t.chanel = 'Total Channel'
```

I have removed spaces from column names to make it easier.

An easier would be to sum up by project id and then insert total rows rather than updating them.